# Why don’t the results of atoi() appear in my program’s output?

Tags: c, atoi

I’m trying to convert arguments passed on the command line to `int` using `atoi`, but it is taking forever no matter whether the string is small or big. Any ideas?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int id;
int v[5];
id=atoi(argv[2]);
v[0]=atoi(argv[3]);
v[1]=atoi(argv[4]);
v[2]=atoi(argv[5]);
v[3]=atoi(argv[6]);
v[4]=atoi(argv[7]);

//conversion must be taking forever; this is never printed
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", id,v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you check `argc`? What is `v`? Post a **complete** minimal example please.

Comment: By the way, you *do* know that output to `stdout` is by default *line buffered*, i.e. nothing is printed until you print a newline. Always end your printouts with a newline.

Comment: Whatever is happening, it is unlikely that "atoi() is taking forever" is a good description of the problem. `atoi()` is a very fast function.

Comment: Stepping through with a debugger would have immediately revealed whether the atoi() calls were gewtting stuck or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html). Change your `printf` line to

```
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", id,v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4]);
```

Note the added newline, `\n`.

Comment: That should be a comment...